# How do I access a class within .append() method in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I've written a Twitter-esque data loader, which appends the data to a table. All of this works.

Next, I need to be able to remove a row by clicking on the delete button. To do this, I'm using a class and a data attribute assigned to an image. All of this works elsewhere in the application.

However, because these table rows are being generated by the .append() method, it appears that the class isn't being recognised. I've proven this by copying and pasting the code (to follow shortly) into the table and then clicking on the delete button, and sure enough, the dialogue appears.

Here's the table:

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="display" id="data-bookmarks">
    <caption>Bookmarks</caption>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col" id="bookmarks-item-name">Title / URL</th>
            <th scope="col" id="bookmarks-item-date">Date Added</th>
            <th scope="col" id="bookmarks-item-delete">x</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4"><em><a href="#load" onclick="paginate(10)">Load Bookmarks</a></em></td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Here's the jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var counter = 0;
    function paginate(limit) {
        counter=counter+limit;
        $(".flash").show();
        $(".flash").fadeIn(400).html("Loading...");
            $.ajax({
                url: "<?php echo config_item('base_url'); ?>notes/jq_get_bookmarks_by_note_as_object/" + '<?php echo strtolower($results['select_note'][0]['note_id']); ?>/' + counter,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                cache: false,
                success: function (element) {
                    $(".flash").hide();
                    $(".load-link").addClass("link-none");
                    for (var i=0;i<element.length;i++) {
                        $("#data-bookmarks").append('<tr><td><a href="<?php echo config_item('base_url'); ?>bookmarks/view/' + element[i].bookmark_id + '"><img src="<?php echo config_item('base_url'); ?>library/images/ui/icons/tables/view.png" alt="view" width="14" height="14" class="icons-actions" /></a>&nbsp;<a href="<?php echo config_item('base_url'); ?>bookmarks/visit/' + element[i].bookmark_id + '" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"><img src="<?php echo config_item('base_url'); ?>library/images/ui/icons/tables/link.png" alt="link" width="14" height="14" class="icons-actions" /></a>&nbsp;<a href="<?php echo config_item('base_url'); ?>bookmarks/edit/' + element[i].bookmark_id + '" title="Edit ' + element[i].title + '">&lsquo;' + element[i].title + '&rsquo;</a></td><td>' + element[i].creation + '</td><td align="left"><img src="<?php echo config_item('base_url'); ?>library/images/ui/buttons/delete.png" class="bookmark-delete" data-bookmark="' + element[i].bookmark_id + '" height="14" width="14" /></td></tr>');
                    }
                }
            }
        );
    }
    paginate(0);
</script>
```

Here's the jQuery to trigger the dialogue and perform the delete:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#dialogue").hide();
    $('.bookmark-delete').click(function(event) {
        var id = $(this).attr("data-bookmark");
        event.preventDefault();
        $("a.action").attr("href", base_url + 'notes/bookmarks/delete/' + id);
        $("#dialogue").css({ position:"absolute", top: event.pageY+15, left: event.pageX-315 });
        $("#dialogue").show();
    });
    $('#close').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#dialogue").hide();
    });
});
```

And finally, here's the dialogue:

```
<div class="dialogue" id="dialogue">
    <div class="message">
        <h3>Delete link to Bookmark</h3>
        <p>Do you want to delete the link to this Bookmark?</p>
    </div>
    <div class="divider"></div>
    <ul class="buttons">
        <li><div id="button-link"><a class="button-link action" href="#">Delete</a></div></li>
        <li><div id="button-link"><a class="button-link" href="#close" id="close">Cancel</a></div></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="cleaner"></div>
</div>
```

If you scroll way out there to the end of the .append() method somewhere, you'll find:

```
class="bookmark-delete" data-bookmark="' + element[i].bookmark_id + '"
```

And that's where the magic appears not to be happening, because jQuery isn't recognising the class.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use event delegation to handle events for dynamically added elements:

If jQuery >= 1.7

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#dialogue").hide();
    $("#data-bookmarks").on('click', '.bookmark-delete', function(event) {
        var id = $(this).attr("data-bookmark");
        event.preventDefault();
        $("a.action").attr("href", base_url + 'notes/bookmarks/delete/' + id);
        $("#dialogue").css({ position:"absolute", top: event.pageY+15, left: event.pageX-315 });
        $("#dialogue").show();
    });
    $('#close').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#dialogue").hide();
    });
});
```

Updated: Based on comments by @MichaelGeary

If jQuery >= 1.4.2 and < 1.7

```
    $('#data-bookmarks').delegate('.bookmark-delete','click',function(event) {
        var id = $(this).attr("data-bookmark");
        event.preventDefault();
        $("a.action").attr("href", base_url + 'notes/bookmarks/delete/' + id);
        $("#dialogue").css({ position:"absolute", top: event.pageY+15, left: event.pageX-315 });
        $("#dialogue").show();
    });
```

If jQuery > 1.3 and < 1.4.2

```
    $('.bookmark-delete').live('click', function(event) {
        var id = $(this).attr("data-bookmark");
        event.preventDefault();
        $("a.action").attr("href", base_url + 'notes/bookmarks/delete/' + id);
        $("#dialogue").css({ position:"absolute", top: event.pageY+15, left: event.pageX-315 });
        $("#dialogue").show();
    });
```

Comment: Hi Arun: "TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$(document).on')" appearing on line 9.

Comment: @WayneSmallman - are you using an older version of jQuery? Also note the edit I made to Arun's answer to use `$("#data-bookmarks").on()` instead of `$(document).on()`. (That's not the reason for `.on` being undefined though - that would be an out of date jQuery most likely.)

Comment: For older versions of jQuery you can use `.delegate()` instead - but note the different argument order.

Comment: I've just gone in and made the switch to 2.0.0 for jQuery and 1.10.3 for jQuery UI: "TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$( "#ui-sortable" ).live')" (which isn't anything to do with the problem at hand) and it the class is now being recognised!

Comment: @WayneSmallman - in new versions of jQuery, use `.on()`, not `.live()`. @ArunPJohny - don't use `.live()` unless you're using jQuery >= 1.3 and < 1.4.2. For jQuery >= 1.4.2 and < 1.7 you should use `.delegate()` instead: `$('#data-bookmarks').delegate('.bookmark-delete','click',function(){...});`

Comment: Okay, I can't use the newer jQuery because it's killing almost everything else on the application.

Comment: 1.5 for jQuery and 1.8 for jQuery UI. I must hasten to add that someone else did the core jQuery work some time ago and I'm picking up and learning as I go along, which is why things are perhaps out of date.

Comment: So you should be using `.delegate()`. It works just like the `.on()` example except the order of the first two arguments is reversed as in my comment above.

Comment: Micheal, your suggestion worked! However, at some point, I'll need to go through everything and drag the damn thing up to date.